# vb.net - click on listview subitem and open window

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview

I'm not sure if this is possible after doing a bunch of googling, but hopefully it is. I have an application that pulls a list of information from a MySQL database and populates a listview (Unfortunately, I can't change to a datagrid at this time.) What I'm tasked to do is make it so that when clicking on a certain column, a window will open and, based on the ID of the row that was clicked on, retrieve another set of results from the same database.

The list view is created as such:

```
   Do While result.Read()
        Dim siteid = (result.Item("idsite").ToString())
        Dim sitename = (result.Item("name").ToString())
        Dim last_import_date = (result.Item("import_finished").ToString())
        Dim last_import_file = (result.Item("file_name").ToString())
        Dim last_line = (result.Item("last_line").ToString())
        Dim status = (result.Item("status").ToString())

        Dim lv As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(siteid)
        lv.SubItems.Add(sitename)
        lv.SubItems.Add(last_import_date)
        lv.SubItems.Add(last_import_file)
        lv.SubItems.Add(last_line)
        lv.SubItems.Add(status)
    Loop
```

So preferably I'd like to click on "Last_import_file" and have that open the window. I've tried a bunch of ItemClicked type commands, but haven't had much luck.

Is what I'm attempting possible? I don't need any special text formatting, just want to register the click and pop open the dialog.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377783/determine-clicked-column-in-listview Have a look at this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. To do this in a Listview it is a bit more complicated than a DataGridView. You'll need to make use of the `ListViewHitTestInfo` class. Using the `MouseDown` Event of your listview, use this code:

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseDown
    Dim info As ListViewHitTestInfo = ListView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    MsgBox(info.Location.ToString())
    If Not IsNothing(info.SubItem) Then
        'info will contain the information of the clicked listview column. You can then go through it's subitems for more information, if any.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! It works and I can get the item I'm clicking on, but is there now a way to check the name of the subitem? I'm trying MessageBox.Show(info.SubItem.Name.ToString), but getting a blank. If I use info.SubItem.Text, I get the value, but now I want to see if I can limit to the column clicked and the text value will change for each row in this column

Comment: @J_D The Name property of the CoumnHeader class is not a design-time property. The reason why the value of the Name property of the ColumnHeader at run time returns an empty string is that this property is not serialized in the InitializeComponent method of the form at all. This seems like a limitation of the designer of the ColumnHeader class, which doesn't serialize the value of the Name property of the ColumnHeader. If you aren't storing anything in the "Tag" property, store your name in that. Hope it helps.

Comment: Tags didn't work either, but it's cool. I'm just going to tell it to ignore the first column (which has a checkbox) and if they click anywhere else it will open the new window. Thanks so much for the help!