# Determine column of header clicked in a ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

Simple question, I need to know the position (column) of a header in a `ListView` when I click it.

For non header cells, I use this:

```
private void listViewMine_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePosition = myListView.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    ListViewHitTestInfo hit = myListView.HitTest(mousePosition);
    int columnindex = hit.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hit.SubItem);
}
```

which comes from:

[Determine clicked column in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377783/determine-clicked-column-in-listview)

Which doesn't work with header... I found nothing on the subject. Is there a way to obtain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ColumnClick` event will only fire if the `ListView.View` is set to `Details`. I am assuming this is what you mean by “header clicked” since there are no headers in any view except “Details”. If this is the case, then the `ColumnClick` event for the `ListView` should give you the value of the column header clicked.

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Column " + e.Column.ToString() + " Clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**THE TAG ATTRIBUTE IS THE CLUE**

What I do is to store the Column Numbers (Nomenclature "KEY" & String of the Column Number) into the .TAG attribute in the Columnheader.

When you click on the tab in the listview, you can derive the Column Number from the transparent TAG.

It's the same way that I use the tag on Text Boxes for identifying fields in the associated database when editing things like Contact Records in a CRM Module of an ERP.

I happen to mostly develop in VB6 but the method is universal.

Sometimes the obvious is the easiest :-)